# LiveCycle ES 2.5 Aws_Action field JavaScript

Tags: adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer, lcds

I have a form that I am designing in Adobe LiveCycle ES 2.5 for a client. 
Quick background for the project: It involves taking an even older PDF and converting it to allow digital signatures with potential Reject/Accept buttons. 
Does anyone know how to determine in the click event (AWS_SUBMIT::click) for the submit button which submit button was actually clicked??
Like the Reject vs Accept button.
The client only has access to Adobe LiveCycle es2.5 workbench/suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS_ACTION field's raw value contains the caption of the button that was clicked, but not until it has been clicked - before that, the rawvalue is null. You can put code in the AWS_SUBMIT button click event to do various things based on the value of AWS_ACTION. I have used it before to do different validation depending on the action taken, eg, if the form is rejected, check that they have entered a comment before allowing it to submit, etc.

The possible values for AWS_ACTION match up with the list of user action names you set in that process task in Workbench.

Comment: AWS_ACTION's rawvalue seems to only get populated if the workflow's assign task operation is not set to Submit via the Reader. 
So in other words, the checkbox labeled "Submit via Reader" underneath the "Presentation & Data" section needs to not be checked for the AWS_ACTION to be populated with the user's action button title.